# How to make an alias myscript="./myscript" from inside the bash script to use it outside

Tags: bash, shell

Inside the script, I would like to make an alias to execute the script like that:

$ devbox

So the script contains this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases

alias devbox="./devbox"

echo "Done"
```

But it's not working:

```
zsh: command not found: devbox
```

EDIT:

What if I would like to have an argument "alias" to my script ($./devbox alias) to set "devbox" as alias?

Comment: Add `. ~/.bashrc` after your alias creation to reload your bashrc maybe ?

Comment: How are your running this script? You have defined the alias to be `bash` and running it under `zsh`?

Answer (score 1):

You want to call `source` on your script.

```
$ cat devbox
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello from devbox"
$ cat setAlias.sh
#!/bin/bash

alias devbox="./devbox"

echo "Done"
$ source ./setAlias.sh
Done
$ devbox
Hello from devbox
$
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you seem to be using `zsh` as your shell, but you write your script in `bash`. Second, more important, is that scripts are executed in subprocesses, so any alias defined in your script is visible only in that script.

If you want to execute script in context of current shell, you have to `source` it instead of executing it:

```
source my_script_+with_alias_definitions
```

or

```
. my_script_+with_alias_definitions
```

Comment: What if I would like to have an argument "alias" to my script ($./devbox alias) to set "devbox" as alias?